# spring boot jndi lookup datasource for WAS liberty

Tags: spring-boot, jndi

Hi Can any one please direct me to the example where I need to do jndi lookup for datasource in WAS liberty server. I need to do this using spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Or I don't understand your question or it is really obvious:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=DS_JNDI_NAME
```

You should place that to your `application.properties`

See the Spring Boot docs:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
and
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource